# how to calculate probability of winning exactly one number at lottery

Tags: probability

There are 38 numbers, I pick 7. What are probabilities I win exactly one number, no more and no less.

Is this possible to calculate.

It would be simple to calculate what are the chances I don't win any number, but how can you calculate chances of winning exactly one?

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that you choose 7 numbers between 1 and 38, and there are 7 winning numbers, and there is exactly one match? If so, are repetitions allowed i.e. can you choose (1,1,1,1,1,1,1)?

Comment: @pwerth: yes, 7 numbers between 1 and 38 and no repetions are allowed. If 16 is selected, it's eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen $7$ numbers. In order for you to match exactly one number, the winning numbers must include $6$ of the $31$ numbers you did not choose.
$$\frac{7\cdot\binom{31}{6}}{\binom{38}{7}}\approx40.839\%$$

Comment: Hi @DanielMathias What about having 5 numbers, I can pick 3. What is the prob? I win exactly 2. Using the formula above, I get the incorrect answer: I can pick on 3 ways 2 numbers out of my selection and I also must include 2 numbers I haven't chosen. There are 10 possible combinations, but 3*2 = 6 so 6/10 is not correct answer. Can you help me understand this please?

Answer (score 0):

In each case, there are $C(n, 7)$ possible choices of winning numbers. If we want to choose exactly one of them correctly, then we have 7 ways to specify which number it is to be, and then $C(n - 7, 6)$ ways to pick six
losing numbers from the $n - 7$ losing numbers.

Thus the probability is
$7 * C(n - 7, 6) / C(n, 7)$ in each case.
$(C(n,7)$ are all the possible outcomes)
(it gets harder to choose one of the winning numbers as the pool of numbers grows).